# Create a sequence conditional on values in other columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a dataframe similar to the following:

```
 df = data.frame(ID1 = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
            ID2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
            flagTag = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
```

I need to create a new field "newField" such that the value increments when flagTag = 1 within group of ID1 and ID2 (thus unique records are identify by the combination of ID1 and ID2).The resulting table should look similar

```
    ID1 ID2 flagTag newField
  1   2   1       0     1
  2   2   1       0     1
  3   2   1       0     1
  4   2   1       0     1
  5   2   1       1     2
  6   2   1       0     2
```

I am trying to do this using dplyr but couldn't come up with a logic to do such manipulation. One way is to go record by record in the dataframe and update "newField" in loop which will be a slow procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option with `ave`

```
df$newField <- with(df, ave(flagTag, ID1, ID2, FUN = cumsum)+1)
df$newField
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newField := cumsum(flagTag) + 1, .(ID1, ID2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's use `cumsum` and `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
    mutate(newField = 1 + cumsum(flagTag))


    ID1   ID2 flagTag newField
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2     1       0        1
2     2     1       0        1
3     2     1       0        1
4     2     1       0        1
5     2     1       1        2
6     2     1       0        2
7     2     1       0        2
```

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I was looking for.